# DOM parser settings to avoid XML Injection attack

Tags: java, security

What are the below settings for a DOM parser used for? Anything wrong in setting these attributes? Could they cause any exceptions?

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();                 
  dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
  dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
  dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(byteArrayInputStream));
```

Comment: did you get the solution for this ? I am looking for same. Please post if you found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

These are generally set to avoid exposure to [XML External Entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_external_entity) (XXE) attacks which can lead to exposure of information on disk ([OWASP details here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing)).

As far as my understanding goes, setting these should not cause any problems. Not setting them, however, could leave you vulnerable to attack.

Answer (score 0):

That helps to avoid the XML External Entity Injection.

I was using HP Fortify SCA(Source Code Analyzer), It  was able to find these kind of issues if you are not specifying these attributes.

You can find more information here:https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet